# 2 forms in 1 view with 1 controller

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, controller

So here is the situation, I have a loginpartial.cshtml, which I put on the page with `RenderAction`

this loginpartial contains an `IsAuthenticated`, where if the user is not authenticated it shows the login form.

Secondly, I have a manage page which contains some fields like firstname etc.
When I push the save button, it saves it nicely to the database. However, the login form also gets called, and I have no idea why.

layout.cshtml:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Login", "User");}
```

LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <div>No login</div>
    }
    else
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "User", FormMethod.Post))
        {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed.")

        <div class="Login">
               //fields here
        </div>

        }
    }
</div>
```

UserController Login:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (isValid(user.Email, user.Password))
            {
                using (MVCV2DbContext MVCV2DbContext = new MVCV2DbContext())
                {
                    var users = MVCV2DbContext.Users.Single(u => u.Email == user.Email);


                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(users.ID.ToString(), false);
                    //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            }

        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

manage.cshtml:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Not all good")
    <div>
        //fields here
    </div>
}
```

usercontroller manage:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Manage(User_Details users)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int U_ID = Convert.ToInt32(GetUserIDFromCookie());

            using (MVCV2DbContext MVCV2DbContext = new MVCV2DbContext())
            {
                var user = MVCV2DbContext.User_Details.SingleOrDefault(u => u.User_ID == U_ID);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.User_FirstName = users.User_FirstName;
                    user.User_Insertions = users.User_Insertions;
                    user.User_LastName = users.User_LastName;

                    MVCV2DbContext.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: can you post the generated HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Login", "User");}
```

in your layout file

will call the action method when ever the view is rendered

you can get around this by moving

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) ... don't run auth code
```

out of the view and into the layout view, or controller (with appropriate changes to the IsAuthenticated Test)

Comment: When adding the IsAuthenticated to the controller method it throws an System.InsufficientExecutionStackException, so that wont work either, i think i need to move it out of the partial view indeed but then i'm gonna have some problems with the user model i'm using to login

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` try `Request.IsAuthenticated`

Also what is your debugging saying?

Comment: Debug is going off on the if (isValid(user.Email, user.Password) function to check if the user is allowed to log on. Also before the login form there is a Request.IsAuthenticated. This generates the rest of the menu if the user is logged in.